# How to use jQuery selected text as variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, push

I have a bunch of arrays, eg:

```
var myArrayName  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var myArrayName2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var myArrayName3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

In my DOM I have elements with `data-name="myArrayName" data-push="7"`, `data-name="myArrayName2" data-push="2"` etc.

I want to select all the elements with `data-name` and then push `data-push` values to them, so:

```
$("*[data-name]").each(function(){
  var arName = $(this).data("name");
  var toPush = $(this).data("push");

  // how do I make the stuff below work?
  // arName.push(toPush);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would select all the elements with the attribute `data-name`

```
var arrDataAttr = new Array();
var arrDataPush = new Array();
$(document).find("[data-attr]").each(function()
{
    arrDataAttr.push($(this).attr("data-attr"));
    arrDataPush.push($(this).attr("data-push"));

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an object ( dictionary, map, whatever you call it ):

```
var arrays = {
  'myArrayName': [],
  'myArrayName2':[],
  'myArrayName3':[]
}
$("*[data-name]").each(function(){
  var arName = $(this).data("name");
  var toPush = $(this).data("push");
  arrays[arName].push(toPush);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this could be to wrap all the arrays under an object to namespace them:

```
var arrays = {
  myArrayName: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  myArrayName2: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  myArrayName3: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
};
```

Then, you can access the arrays by their name, like this:

```
// to access the first array:
arrays["myArrayName"];
```

The final code looks like this:

```
$("[data-name]").each(function(){
  var $item = $(this);
  var arName = $item.data("name");
  var toPush = $item.data("push");

  arrays[arName].push(toPush);
});
```

**Notes:**

- Please note that I'm caching the $(this) variable, if you want to know why, check [this](https://ttmm.io/tech/selector-caching-jquery/)
- If you want to know more about accessing object properties with JavaScript, check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Answer (score 1):

Try adjusting names of array variables , `data-*` attribute , using `$.each()` called on arrays , select element having `data-name` ending with current `index` of loop

```js
var myArrayName0 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var myArrayName1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var myArrayName2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

$.each([myArrayName0, myArrayName1, myArrayName2], function(index, arr) {
  arr.push($("[data-name$=" + index + "]").data("push"))
});

console.log(myArrayName0, myArrayName1, myArrayName2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div data-name="myArrayName0" data-push="7"></div>
<div data-name="myArrayName1" data-push="2"></div>
<div data-name="myArrayName2" data-push="1"></div>
```